# how to get the 1 million-th click of a website

Tags: web-services, web, memcached, distributed-computing

I often heard this question coming from different sources, but never got a good idea of the technologies to achieve this. Can anyone shed some lights? The question is: you have a website which has high volume of users access per day. Your website is deployed in a distributed manner, have multiple webservers and load balancers responding incoming requests from lots of locations. How do you get the 1000000th user access, and show him a special page saying "congrats, you are our 1000000th visitor!". Assuming you had a distributed backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to trade off performance or accuracy.  The simplest way to do this would be have a memcached instance keep track of your visitor counts, or some other datastore with an atomic increment operation.  Since there is only a single source of truth, only 1 visitor will get the message.  This will delay the loading of your page by the roundtrip to the store at minimum.

If you can't afford the delay, then you will have to trade off accuracy.  A distributed data store will not be able to atomically increment the field any faster than a single instance.  Every web server can read and write to a local node, but another node at another datacenter may also reach 1 million users counts before the transactions are reconciled.  In that case 2 or more people may get the 1 millionth user message.

It is possible to do so after the fact.  Eventually, the data store will reconcile the increments, and your application can decide on a strict ordering.  However, if you have already decided that a single atomic request takes too long, then this logic will take place too late to render your page.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with jQuery, for example:

```
$("#linkOfInterest").click(function() { //code for updating a variable/record that contains the current number of clicks });
```

CSS:

```
a#linkOfInterest {
//style goes here 
}
```

somewhere in the html  :

```
<a id="linkOfInterest" href="somepage.htm"></a>
```

Comment: actually I expect more detailed design answer, like how to design the lock or the variable, how to distribute the variable across clusters. So that it can accurately catch the 1000000th click. You know, there must be a lot of concurrent accesses and there are lots of webservers load balancers for this, how to design a system to guarantee this.